# Dynamically created SVG animation not working with Angular but vanilla

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I'm creating a SVG with points and paths dynamically by looping through an array of points.
You can see the example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-anim).
I want to create a loop animation so I had to reference between `animateMotion`'s by their ids. It seems like these references are not working properly but when copying the SVG node from devtools and pasting it into [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lofexuhoko/edit?html,output), it works like expected.

Any ideas how to get this working with Angular?

Comment: `repeatCount="indefinite"` doesn't work?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-anim-odrdtd?file=app/device-map.component.html

Comment: It's not a problem with the SVG animation itself as it works when copied to plain HTML as you can see in the jsbin example

Comment: I think SMIL is not a good choice here ... maybe I should go with CSS animations instead